# SSIS 2008 R2 OnProgress logging for Execute SQL tasks truncates SQL statements

Tags: sql-server-2008, logging, ssis

My Execute SQL tasks are configured to log to the automatically created dbo.sysssislog table. I'd really like to log the full text of any SQL statements in the 2K messages column but SSIS is only recording the first 40-ish characters. Is there a way to override that truncation? Am I trying to solve the wrong problem in that there's a better way to accomplish my goal?

I created a new (simple) package to demonstrate my issue ...

Expression in Execute SQL task

[image: My SQL task expression]

Logging OnProgress to the default SSIS generated table via SSIS generated proc

[image: Logging config]

The truncated data in the table (note ellipsis)

[image]

Comment: May you show a diagram of your package?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are seeing is an artifact of how the default OnProgress logger is built (and something I never noticed). Why it is structured as it is, would be a question for Microsoft.

If you explicitly invoke `sp_ssis_addlogentry` then it will correctly log text up to nvarchar(2048). However, if you log the OnProgress event, the text that is passed to the stored proc has been truncated by the inner workings of the event logger.

Two notes of caution on your supplied screenshot.

1. You're building a string within a component's Expression builder. I strongly caution against that for the simple fact that if you have an incorrect expression in there, you have no capacity to debug it. Set a breakpoint on the object, great. You *still* can't inspect the value of the what you've built as it is internal to the object. Instead, I find I have better success doing all the string building within a Variable and then my Task's expression is simply `@[MyVariable]`
2. Prior to the 2012 release, there is a 4k character limit on expressions. You can initialize and assign strings greater than that length but if you attempt to use an expression to do so, it doesn't work. I can't recall now whether it truncates or flat out fails.

On with the **tl;wr;**

### Round 1, Script approach

I created two SSIS Variables: Query and QueryLength. 
The Value of Query is the following query I ran in SSMS

```
SELECT REPLICATE('SELECT 100 AS col UNION ALL ', 70) + ' SELECT 0'
```

Query is an Integer value using the following expression: LEN(@[User::Query]) It should have a value of 1968

I added a Script Task to my package and used the following code

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace ST_b3643f349be14c7a9d004a35aaa0422e
{
    [Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.SSISScriptTaskEntryPointAttribute]
    public partial class ScriptMain : Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.VSTARTScriptObjectModelBase
    {

        public void Main()
        {
            // User::Query,User::QueryLength
            string query = this.Dts.Variables["User::Query"].Value.ToString();
            string queryLength = this.Dts.Variables["User::QueryLength"].Value.ToString();

            bool fireAgain = false;
            string message = string.Format("Query => {0}", query);
            this.Dts.Events.FireInformation(0, "Query", message, string.Empty, 0, ref fireAgain);
        this.Dts.Events.FireProgress(message, 50, 0, 1, "query", ref fireAgain);

            message = string.Format("QueryLength => {0}", queryLength);
            this.Dts.Events.FireInformation(0, "QueryLength", message, string.Empty, 0, ref fireAgain);
        this.Dts.Events.FireProgress(message, 50, 0, 1, "queryLength", ref fireAgain);

            Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
        }

        enum ScriptResults
        {
            Success = Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult.Success,
            Failure = Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult.Failure
        };
    }
}
```

Finally, I turned on Logging to SQL Server and logged OnInformation & OnProgress events

I executed the package and then ran the following query

```
USE msdb
SELECT
    S.source
,   S.event
,   LEN(S.message) AS lenMsg
,   S.message
FROM
    dbo.sysssislog AS S
WHERE
    S.event = 'OnInformation'
    OR S.event = 'OnProgress';
```

As you can see, it records more than 40ish characters.

[image]

### Round 2, Execute SQL Task approach

Based on the comments below, I reworked the package to use an Execute SQL Task that invokes `sp_ssis_addlogentry` I'm still getting the full message logged to the `message` column of `dbo.sysssislog`

The following Biml represents my package. Install [BIDS Helper](http://bidshelper.codeplex.com/), add an empty Biml file and substitute this. Correct the Data Source value in line 3 and click generate, and woosh a working package.

```
<Biml xmlns="http://schemas.varigence.com/biml.xsd">
    <Connections>
        <OleDbConnection Name="CM_OLE" ConnectionString="Data Source=localhost\dev2014;Initial Catalog=msdb;Provider=SQLNCLI10.1;Integrated Security=SSPI;Auto Translate=False;" />
    </Connections>
    <Packages>
        <Package ConstraintMode="Linear" Name="so_28101525">
            <Variables>
                <Variable DataType="String" Name="Query">SELECT 100 AS col UNION ALL SELECT 100 AS col UNION ALL SELECT 100 AS col UNION ALL SELECT 100 AS col UNION ALL SELECT 100 AS col UNION ALL SELECT 100 AS col UNION ALL SELECT 100 AS col UNION ALL SELECT 100 AS col UNION ALL SELECT 100 AS col UNION ALL SELECT 100 AS col UNION ALL SELECT 100 AS col UNION ALL SELECT 100 AS col UNION ALL SELECT 100 AS col UNION ALL SELECT 100 AS col UNION ALL SELECT 100 AS col UNION ALL SELECT 100 AS col UNION ALL SELECT 100 AS col UNION ALL SELECT 100 AS col UNION ALL SELECT 100 AS col UNION ALL SELECT 100 AS col UNION ALL SELECT 100 AS col UNION ALL SELECT 100 AS col UNION ALL SELECT 100 AS col UNION ALL SELECT 100 AS col UNION ALL SELECT 100 AS col UNION ALL SELECT 100 AS col UNION ALL SELECT 100 AS col UNION ALL SELECT 100 AS col UNION ALL SELECT 100 AS col UNION ALL SELECT 100 AS col UNION ALL SELECT 100 AS col UNION ALL SELECT 100 AS col UNION ALL SELECT 100 AS col UNION ALL SELECT 100 AS col UNION ALL SELECT 100 AS col UNION ALL SELECT 100 AS col UNION ALL SELECT 100 AS col UNION ALL SELECT 100 AS col UNION ALL SELECT 100 AS col UNION ALL SELECT 100 AS col UNION ALL SELECT 100 AS col UNION ALL SELECT 100 AS col UNION ALL SELECT 100 AS col UNION ALL SELECT 100 AS col UNION ALL SELECT 100 AS col UNION ALL SELECT 100 AS col UNION ALL SELECT 100 AS col UNION ALL SELECT 100 AS col UNION ALL SELECT 100 AS col UNION ALL SELECT 100 AS col UNION ALL SELECT 100 AS col UNION ALL SELECT 100 AS col UNION ALL SELECT 100 AS col UNION ALL SELECT 100 AS col UNION ALL SELECT 100 AS col UNION ALL SELECT 100 AS col UNION ALL SELECT 100 AS col UNION ALL SELECT 100 AS col UNION ALL SELECT 100 AS col UNION ALL SELECT 100 AS col UNION ALL SELECT 100 AS col UNION ALL SELECT 100 AS col UNION ALL SELECT 100 AS col UNION ALL SELECT 100 AS col UNION ALL SELECT 100 AS col UNION ALL SELECT 100 AS col UNION ALL SELECT 100 AS col UNION ALL SELECT 100 AS col UNION ALL SELECT 100 AS col UNION ALL SELECT 100 AS col UNION ALL SELECT 0</Variable>
                <Variable DataType="Int32" Name="QueryLength" EvaluateAsExpression="true">LEN(@[User::Query])</Variable>
                <Variable DataType="String" Name="EventType" Namespace="Log">OnProgress</Variable>
                <Variable DataType="String" Name="Source" Namespace="Log">OnProgress</Variable>
            </Variables>
            <Tasks>
                <ExecuteSQL ConnectionName="CM_OLE" Name="Log it">
                    <DirectInput>EXECUTE dbo.sp_ssis_addlogentry
    @event = ?
,   @computer = ?
,   @operator = ?
,   @source = ?
,   @sourceid = ?
,   @executionid = ?
,   @starttime = ?
,   @endtime = ?
,   @datacode = 0
,   @databytes = NULL
,   @message = ?;
</DirectInput>
                    <Parameters>
                        <Parameter DataType="String" VariableName="Log.EventType" Name="0" />
                        <Parameter DataType="String" VariableName="System.MachineName" Name="1" />
                        <Parameter DataType="String" VariableName="System.UserName" Name="2" />
                        <Parameter DataType="String" VariableName="Log.Source" Name="3" />
                        <Parameter DataType="String" VariableName="System.ExecutionInstanceGUID" Name="4" />
                        <Parameter DataType="String" VariableName="System.ExecutionInstanceGUID" Name="5" />
                        <Parameter DataType="String" VariableName="System.ContainerStartTime" Name="6" />
                        <Parameter DataType="String" VariableName="System.ContainerStartTime" Name="7" />
                        <Parameter DataType="String" VariableName="User.Query" Name="8" />
                    </Parameters>

                </ExecuteSQL>
            <ExecuteSQL ConnectionName="CM_OLE" Name="Run Query">
                <VariableInput VariableName="User.Query" />
            </ExecuteSQL>
        </Tasks>
        <LogProviders>
            <SqlServerLogProvider ConnectionName="CM_OLE" Name="SQL Log Provider" /> 
        </LogProviders>
        <LogEvents>
            <LogEvent EventName="OnProgress"></LogEvent>
        </LogEvents>
            </Tasks>
        </Package>
    </Packages>
</Biml>
```

That results in this package being generated.

[image]

The results of running a profiler trace while the package runs

```
exec sp_executesql
    N'exec sp_ssis_addlogentry @P1, @P2, @P3, @P4, @P5, @P6, @P7, @P8, @P9, @P10, @P11'
,   N'@P1 nvarchar(4000),@P2 nvarchar(4000),@P3 nvarchar(4000),@P4 nvarchar(4000),@P5 uniqueidentifier,@P6 uniqueidentifier,@P7 datetime2(7),@P8 datetime2(7),@P9 int,@P10 varbinary(8000),@P11 nvarchar(4000)'
,   N'OnProgress'
,   N'Rohan'
,   N'home\billinkc'
,   N'Log it'
,   '795A8317-110B-423E-BFD3-2E90AB021D53'
,   'DE260D62-A2BC-4C19-A48D-CA6526F1B3EC'
,   '2015-01-23 10:28:38'
,   '2015-01-23 10:28:38'
,   100
,   0x
,   N'Executing query "EXECUTE dbo.sp_ssis_addlogentry
        @event = ?
    ,  ...".'
```

This stands in contrast to the manually generated call to sp_ssis_logentry

Comment: +1 for all that effort! I too am getting full message logging in  Script tasks but I'm not in my Execute SQL tasks. When I get back to the office I'll post a diagram as suggested by Jeff. Maybe there'll be something obvious in that.

Comment: @ddevogel Ah, so you have your own insert statement going to the sysssislog or are you using the stored procedure (... I *think* there's one)

Comment: Nope, using the proc; everything is default behavior. When I enabled logging the table and proc got created automatically - both with the 'message' column defined as varchar(2048). I have plenty of long messages in the table just not SQL task OnProgresses with full queries. I did notice those log entries for queries end in ellipses so it seems something (not me) is knowingly truncating before the logging proc call.

Comment: @ddevogel I'm able to use sp_ssis_addlogentry just fine with long text. Perhaps edit your question to show your usage

Comment: Thanks for the help Bill. You've confirmed my suspicion about OnProgress. I'll try the direct sp invoke.